# Highlighting Cell or Row IF a cell in that row has been conditionally formatted

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a large excel document with over 200 columns and hundreds of rows. I have set a bunch of conditional formatting rules that will turn a cell red if it's text is not correct. (I'm doing VLOOKUP formulas on a different sheet so each row has to have specific text or the VLOOKUP will error.) The problem is, with so many rows and columns it's hard to find the cells that are red. I'm looking for a way to highlight the whole row yellow or just the first or second cell of that row yellow IF there is a red conditionally formatted cell in that row.

I have searched google for hours for a way to do this and everything is pointing to "it's not possible" which I find hard to believe. I was able to write a VBA script that works if I fill a cell red, but it wont work when it's red from the conditional formatting rule. (Note, I'm just learning VBA)

```
Sub FindingColor()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r As Range
    Dim nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long, ic As Long

    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r1.Rows.Count + r1.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = r1.Row

    For ic = nFirstRow To nLastRow
        Set r2 = Intersect(r1, Rows(ic))
        For Each r In r2
            If r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                r2(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    Next ic

End Sub
```

Comment: conditional formatting is able to highlight the entire row red given a cell is the row match the condition. u have to use the formula option of conditional formatting. so no VBA is required.

Comment: You can use CF to highlight the one cell red and all others yellow using exactly the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the DisplayFormat property to test for changes made by conditional formatting.

```
Sub FindingColor()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r As Range
    Dim nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long, ic As Long

    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r1.Rows.Count + r1.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = r1.Row

    For ic = nFirstRow To nLastRow
        Set r2 = Intersect(r1, Rows(ic))
        For Each r In r2
            If r.displayformat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                r2(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    Next ic

End Sub
```

You also might use a check against the conditions that actually switched on the CFR.

Comment: Thank yo so much! You are my hero!